# Why is uicontrol function in matlab returning a double value?

Tags: matlab

I am using this command to create a uicontrol object

```
h = uicontrol('style','listbox','max',10,'min',1,'Position',[200 200 200 200],'string',sheets,'Callback',@listbox1_Callback);
```

It is returning random double values (0.017, 0.035 etc.) for h and thus giving error while executing callback since no object handle is being created.

Complete code

```
FileName = uigetfile('*.xlsx','Select the data file',filepath);
[status,sheets,xlFormat] = xlsfinfo(FileName)
h = uicontrol('style','listbox','max',10,'min',1,'Position',[200 200 200 200],'string',sheets,'Callback',@listbox1_Callback);
```

Comment: What MATLAB version? Cannot reproduce in R2014b. Are you sure you don't have any other function/variable called `uicontrol`?

Comment: 2014a. No, there is no other function/variable called uicontrol.

Comment: Code in the question, not in the comments!

Comment: How are you invoking the callback, and what error are you getting?

Comment: is it possible you overwrite `h` afterward? If you haven't already done this, can you put a bullet point at `h=unicontrol(...)` and check the value of `h`?

Answer (score 1):

That is the behavior of different Matlab versions. To get a property of the uicontrol, this works no matter h is double or handle:

```
str = get(h, 'String'); % work for all versions
```

Later Matlab supports more convenient way for this:

```
str = h.String; % only supported for later versions where h is handle
```

If you like to use the latter syntax for earlier version, you can do this:

```
h = handle(h); % convert double to handle for earlier matlab
```

Then you can do the same as for later matlab. The above command won't hurt for later matlab versions, if you worry about compatibility to different versions.